# QtCreator not building. (Windows)

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qmake

so while trying to assist a friend in setting up QT I ran into a odd problem with his system. Whenever he attempts to build a simple 'Hello World' app through QTCreator using all the default settings, he gets some odd compiler output diffrent to my own. I know for a fact that his install, and project setup was done verbatim exactly as I did it, I even had him uninstall and reinstall along side me to test that.

Everything with QtCreator works out of the box on my end, and I after a few hours of uninstalling / reinstalling on both machines via remote control I am out of ideas.

**HIS COMPILER OUTPUT**

```
01:33:52: Running steps for project untitled...
01:33:52: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" clean
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug clean
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/gian_/Documents/untitled'
del debug\main.o
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/gian_/Documents/untitled'
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release clean
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/gian_/Documents/untitled'
del release\main.o
Could Not Find C:\Users\gian_\Documents\untitled\release\main.o
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/gian_/Documents/untitled'
01:33:52: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
01:33:52: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
01:33:52: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/gian_/Documents/untitled'
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wextra -Wall -W -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I. -I..\..\..\..\Qt\5.9.1\mingw53_32\mkspecs\win32-g++  -o debug\main.o main.cpp
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o debug\untitled.exe debug/main.o  
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/gian_/Documents/untitled'
01:33:53: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
01:33:53: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

**MY COMPILER OUTPUT**

```
00:21:00: Running steps for project untitled3...
00:21:00: Starting: "C:\Qt\5.9.1\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Users\jay\Documents\untitled3\untitled3.pro -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
Info: creating stash file C:\Users\jay\Documents\build-untitled3-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\.qmake.stash
00:21:00: The process "C:\Qt\5.9.1\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
00:21:00: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" qmake_all
mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for 'qmake_all'.
00:21:00: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
00:21:00: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/jay/Documents/build-untitled3-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wextra -Wall -W -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I..\untitled3 -I. -I..\..\..\..\Qt\5.9.1\mingw53_32\mkspecs\win32-g++  -o debug\main.o ..\untitled3\main.cpp
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o debug\untitled3.exe debug/main.o  
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/jay/Documents/build-untitled3-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
00:21:01: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
00:21:01: Running steps for project untitled1...
00:21:01: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
00:21:01: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/jay/Documents/build-untitled1-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
mingw32-make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/jay/Documents/build-untitled1-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
00:21:01: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
00:21:01: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

I could not find any other issues like this, I have tried searching.

QtCreator will not build 'Hello World'
QtCreator build failed mingw
QtCreator not building with qmake.exe
QtCreator build error using MinGW

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to look this over.

**EDIT:** I was asked to provide our Envrioment Variables, so here you go.

[His Environment Vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4nse.png)

[My Environment Vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxLrT.png)

Comment: could you guys do a diff of the environment variables? perhaps his is pointing to something odd?

Comment: @SamerTufail did you want the Path or our entire Environment Vars from windows with all the other bits?

Comment: @SamerTufail I added screen shots of our vars in windows, thanks.

Comment: I dont see your environment variables either for MinGW. Check this link: http://embeddedprogrammer.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/windows-environment-variables-for-mingw.html

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

So, after much issue we discovered that the description was he was getting messages in his build in regards to his "RELEASE" settings as well, we still have not solved the issue as to why his build chain is different, even though we have identical setups.

So to anyone who MAY have this issue, simply build in debug, build in release, then switch back to debug and run it, worked for my friend.